# Can't create WVD Resource Pool

Tags: windows, azure, entra-id

I'm trying to get Windows Virtual Desktop set up, and when it's going through the steps of provisioning my resource pools i get this error:

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'joindomain'. Error message: "Exception(s) occured while joining Domain 'swiftchipinc.com'"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionwindowstroubleshoot "},{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'joindomain'. Error message: "Exception(s) occured while joining Domain 'swiftchipinc.com'"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionwindowstroubleshoot "}]}

Comment: Is your Active Directory domain **swiftchipinc.com**?

Answer (score 2):

> VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'joindomain'.
> Error message: "Exception(s) occured while joining Domain '***.com'"

Looks like the info you provided for domain joining are not correct.
You should review your domain joining info, including username, password and OU path (if used).
WVD hosts need to join your AD domain, and you need to provide proper info for doing that.

(Also, your VMs need to use the correct domain DNS and be able to contact a Domain Controller in order to join your AD domain.)

Comment: Totally agree with Massimo, in addition to this question, most likely your VNET has no custom DNS configured, usually a WVD environment has a custom DNS in VNET where it runs pointing to your AD private IP.

Comment: @Taguada I'm currently working on a WVD deployment for a customer who doesn't specify DNS servers in their VNet config, because they have multiple domains. This is a royal pain.
I'd totally want for Azure VNets to be able to specify DNS settings at the subnet level, not only for the whole VNet. There's a feature request for this, please vote it if you feel like so:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/9310917-allow-dns-servers-to-be-advertised-per-subnet-inst